# How to change #define value

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I know `#define` must be constant but please give me any good tips.

In my case, I define a constant value by `#define` (e.g. `#define kImageQuality 0.7`).
However, I would like to change the constant value from `Settings.Bundle` before opening an app.
That means to change the constant value, doesn't it?
Is that any way to implement as my aim?

It should change to instance variable instead of #define?
Any tips given by you that would be really appreciated.

Comment: It would have to be a non-constant global variable.

Comment: you can define a property and set its default value on viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad and change it later in the future..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible because this:

```
#define constant 3
...
y = x + constant
```

Is **completely** equivalent to this:

```
y = x + 3
```

`#define`d constants are replaced by their value in the preprocessing stage before the code is even compiled. To change the value dynamically, you have to either use a global variable, or some other persistent mechanism like `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: As long as enabling to change a constant value within - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions, I would be happy. So I am going for "y = x + 3" program. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

`#define` constants are replaced before compilation even begins by the preprocessor (e.g. `kImageQuality` gets replaced by `0.7` before compilation). Therefore loading it before the app starts is impossible as the app does not recompile every time. You need to use a variable:

```
float imageQuality = 0.7f;
```